# How can I find the total number of monitors my Linux laptop is capable of supporting?

Tags: multi-monitor

I've tried looking for answers, and everything I've found is about either:

A.) How to add a new monitor, or

B.) How to manage the monitors I already have connected.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. How can I check what the total number of monitors is that I can hypothetically have connected all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Limit will be your hardware, not Linux. You would need to look up the specifications of your graphics card, that's where this sort of thing is listed. For example, this is my system:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX] driver: nvidia v: 465.31 
  Device-3: Logitech Webcam C270 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
  Device-4: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting 
  resolution: 1: 2560x1440~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz 3: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.1.3
```

I have two graphics cards, the onboard Intel one and a discrete Nvidia. Searching for ["Intel HD Graphics 530"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Intel%20HD%20Graphics%20530%22&ia=web) let me find the [official Intel support page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/88345/graphics/graphics-for-6th-generation-intel-processors/intel-hd-graphics-530.html) for this chip which informed me that it supports 3 monitors:

[image: Screenshot of the relevant section of Intel's support page]

I haven't been able to find the equivalent page for my Nvidia card since it's quite old now and probably no longer supported (the Nvidia pages give me 404 errors), but the principle is the same: you need to get this information from your card's manufacturer. In any case, I doubt the discrete card will be relevant for the number of monitors anyway.

Comment: Thank you for this! This helped me get my answer!